# Custom function - for each character within a string

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

G'day,

I am trying to put a custom formula together, which has very simple logic. Basically, for every string that I pass to it I want it to remove all the non-number characters and apply a leading zero to each digit found (if digit is < 10)

For instance:

**function('gi-1/1')** should return 0101 (or simply 101 as Integer). Respectively 'gi-1/3' would return 0103 (or 103).

I am struggling to achieve this with mcode and I was hoping if you could help me out. Here is what I managed to put together so far (also, I only want to do this if the number is < 100)

```
let if_order = (if_name) => 
    let
        Result_1 = Text.Select(if_name, {"0".."9"}) as number,
        Result_2 = if Result_1 < 100 then Text.Combine({Text.Start(Result_1, 1), "0", Text.Middle(Result_1,1)}) else Result_1
    in
        Result_2
in
    if_order
```

The error I am getting is quite confusing. Basically it's saying:

"We cannot convert the value "11" to type Number"

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Text.Select` returns text but you're asking it to be a number. You need to do the conversion more explicitly.

Try this modification (outputs the result as text):

```
let if_order = (if_name) => 
    let
        Result_1 = Text.Select(if_name, {"0".."9"}),
        Result_2 = if Number.FromText(Result_1) < 100
                   then Text.Combine({Text.Start(Result_1, 1), "0", Text.Middle(Result_1,1)})
                   else Result_1
    in
        Result_2
in
    if_order
```

If you want to return an integer, you could use math instead of string manipulation:

```
let if_order = (if_name) => 
    let
        Result_1 = Number.FromText(Text.Select(if_name, {"0".."9"})),
        Result_2 = if Result_1 < 100
                   then 100 * Number.IntegerDivide(Result_1, 10)
                            + Number.Mod(Result_1, 10)
                   else Result_1
    in
        Result_2
in
    if_order
```

Comment: if you don't mind me asking here - is there an easy way to use similar function but to add a custom character. e.g. `function("test-123")` to return tAeAsAtA-1A2A3A? Hope this makes sense, basically "foreach c in $string  -> $c1A". Hope this makes sense

Comment: = Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(SourceText), each _ & "A"))

Comment: Thank you!! I should have paid more attention to your answer earlier!

Answer (score 1):

try this

removes all non-numbers
splits into a list, appends a zero, recombines

```
(TheText as text) =>
let Source = Text.Remove(TheText, { Character.FromNumber(32)..Character.FromNumber(47), Character.FromNumber(58)..Character.FromNumber(255) } ),
done = Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(Source ), each "0"&_))
in done
```

Comment: The `List.Transform` is a neat function (and frequently useful when working with text). Is the `Text.Remove` just to demonstrate something different than `Text.Select`?

Comment: No. It was just the first thing that came to mind, filtering out the non-numeric as opposed to actively selecting the numeric.  The question was blank when I arrived, didn't see you had posted an answer

Comment: The OP uses `Text.Select`, so I figured you'd seen that part. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I am notoriously non-observant